# SQL : Add unique ID and append a string

Tags: sql-server

I have the following for adding a unique ID to the field in SQL 2014 Mgmt Studio

```
ADD MY_ID INT IDENTITY (1,1)
```

Is there a way where I can also append a fixed text next to the unique ID?

Problem lies where the column is set to INT to begin with so even if I add two columns where one is set as the ID and the other a set string, I can't concat it without a transformation.

In other words, can I do:

```
ADD MY_ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) + "Myfile.docx"
```

Thanks

Comment: No, but you could add a computed column of varchar data type which combines the identity + your string.

Comment: So..
ALTER TABLE MTABLE
ADD CONCAT_COLUMN VARCHAR(255) 'Myfile.docx"?

Is there a way to do the operation and the concatenation under a single transaction?

Comment: I get the following : Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 55
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'mytable.doc' to data type int.
The field is varchar

update [mytable]
 set CONCAT_FIELD = MY_ID + 'mytable.doc'

Comment: I'm unsure if this will work... I think the computed value will have the My_ID avaialbe at time of generation.  `ALTER TABLE MTABLE ADD CONCAT_COLUMN Concat(cast(My_ID as varchar(10)), 'Myfile.docx')`

Comment: If you dont want to alter the table you could create a view and use the view instead of the table

Comment: syntax failure unfortunately. near '('

Comment: @Aram syntax failure when attempting to what?

Comment: ALTER TABLE [mytable] ADD [Concat_Field] cast ([ID_Field] as varchar (255)) + 'Myfile.doc')

Comment: The question for me is why bother with this? If it is just a hard coded value it doesn't belong as part of your identity in the first place. This is adding meaning to an incrementing value. What is the point of storing that data over and over and over in your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter your table and add a computed column :
see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

```
alter table dbo.MyTable
add MyComputedID as convert(varchar, my_id) + 'Myfile.docx'
```

or you can create a view :

```
create view dbo.vwMyTable as
  select  my_id,
          foo1,
          foo2,
          ...
          convert(varchar, my_id) + 'Myfile.docx' as MyComputedID
  from    dbo.MyTable
```